# AX 2012 access denied error when clicking on packing slip

Tags: security, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to customize my own security role for users. I need to give access to the packing slip under pick and pack tab in all sales orders.

When clicked, an error shows up stating that Access denied: SalesFormLetter_PackingSlip.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your security role has access to the privilege "Process Sales Packing Slip" (`SalesPackingSlipGenerate`).

I also remember one project (AX 2012 R2) where we modified the report. Suddenly some users that previously had access to the report could not open it anymore. Investigation revealed that although usually AX derives the necessary rights, it somehow mixed them up (we never found out why). To resolve it, we added `SalesPackingSlipDP.processReport` to the server methods of the permissions node of the privilege. Not sure if this is your issue though.